# Android how to replicate info from one activity to other concurrently

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I would like to know if it is possible to replicate in my visible Activity changes which are ocurring in a not visible activity.

For example, I have a loop with an integer incrementing in Activity A, then I invoke Activity B passing the integer as an extra.

Is there a way to see reflected the increments (which are ocurring in A) in B?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **int** is a primitive type, a variable with **int** type will not be changed when you pass it into **activity B**.

I would suggest you pass in a wrapper of **int** type (i.e. `class IntWrapper { int value; }`)

The change will be reflected when you increase `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass data using broadcast recievers:

In the listening activity/fragment create the reciever and register it (do this in oncreate or onresume or something, maybe even onrestart). The activity will now listen for a broadcast and you test if it's a broadcast meant for that reciever using a built in keyword. Because a the broadcast is done using an intent, you can also get and use other data stored in that intent (like your int):

```
    my_broadcast_reciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_buy_activity"))
            //do whatever
            }               
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(my_broadcast_reciever, new IntentFilter("theKeywordThisBCRRespondsTo"));
```

Dont forget to unregister any recievers in onpause or ondestroy (whatever makes most sense depending on where you register the reciever):

```
    {unregisterReceiver(my_broadcast_reciever);
```

Now, in the activity/fragment which you want to use to send the data, fire off the intent like so (you might want to create and keep the intent at a higher level so you don't keep on creating a new object every update):

```
    Intent sintent = new Intent("theKeywordThisBCRRespondsTo");
    //maybe also do: sintent.addInt(int); or something
    sendBroadcast(sintent);
```

Keep in mind, this might be a little overkill in certain cases, but it is a great way to communicate and transmit data between activities/fragments.

Comment: I would be against this approach. BroadcastReceiver is good for inter application communication. It is too much overkill to use it within the same app.